# error to integrate Admob on application android (the application crashes)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, admob

when i am trying to start my application on my device, the application crashes and i get this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
```

i already trying with the solutions proposed on stackoverflow but it doesn't work with this error.

the file build.gradle (including the dependencies)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:16'
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.recipes.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.ads.AdView` is the package name used before the integration of the Mobile Ads SDK with Google Play services. Try using the current one, [`com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView), in your layouts instead.